# Google Sheets Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, comments

Is there a way to add a comment column to the right of a pivot table, and ensure that the comments added also move correctly when the pivot table is refreshed?

For example,
If I have a pivot table that is sorted by flowers and the number of each, can i add a column outside of the pivot table to comment if it is purchased, for example?

Thanks

I tried to freeze the rows but the comments do not move with the refreshed date

Comment: Is there a context in which the comments could be included as source data for the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

A mix of Google Sheets tools, including array formulas, the ARRAYFORMULA function, and the INDIRECT function, can be used to do this.
•

1. After creating a Pivot table, you need to insert a new column for
   comments
2. Then, link the comments to the pivot table
3. Enter the following formula in the cell directly adjacent to your
   pivot table (in the same row). It should be changed to the cell
   reference for your comment. part checks to see if the comment cell
   is empty; if it is, the comment text will be displayed; if it's not, an
   empty string gets shown.

= ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2 : A), " ", A2))

**Edit 2**:

You might need to think about using an alternate technique, like a script or macro, to ensure that comments remain next to the appropriate line and move with the pivot table when it is refreshed. Here is an example of a general Google Apps Script approach to this:
Google Apps scripts are possible to put together.

1. Launch your Google Sheets file.
2. The script editor is accessed by clicking Extensions > Apps Script.
3. Create a script to link rows' comments.
4. You must create a unique script that links comments to particular
   Pivot Table rows. When a remark is made or updated, the onEdit
   trigger may be used to record the event and subsequently save the
   comment with the data for the relevant row.
5. Putting in the trigger
6. Create a "onEdit" trigger that launches the onEdit function by
   clicking the clock icon (Triggers) in the script editor. Examine the
   script:

Now, your pivot table should have comments. These comments should automatically be linked to the correct rows by the script. Pivot Table refresh: The comments should update with the data when you refresh your pivot table.

Point number 3-related js code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var comment = range.getComment();
  var row = range.getRow();

  if (sheet.getName() === "name of your table") {
    // Store the comment in a specific column next to the Pivot Table data.
    sheet.getRange(row, sheet.getLastColumn() + 1).setValue(comment);
  }
}
```

**Note**: Do change the *name of your table* with your own table's name.

(*This is my first answer here to other's questions, kindly rectify if any format is wrong*)

Comment: This did not work.             I need the comments column to stay next to the correct line. when i refresh the pivot table, the cell that i put a comment in does not move with the pivot table. It stays in the same place.

Comment: @RosannaCaruso, I added a new section under the Edit 2 (in bold). You can try to follow these steps to resolve the issue. I am not a tremendous expert but you try with these steps.